# Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking View filtered to include full domains not showing data

Tags: google-analytics

So I've set up cross domain tracking in Tag Manager, but the client would like to see the full domain names in his all pages report. I've created a new view with the below filter to add the domains, but the view isn't pulling in any data, can't even see activity under the realtime view, while the regular all website data view is working just fine. Am I doing something wrong in the filter:

[Filter Screegrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmKoH.png)

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, had User ID reports on by accident.